# Why add button in JavaScript does not remember values

Tags: javascript

I need a help with JavaScript add button and inner HTML in JavaScript function. When I do a validation and go on onclick everything is ok...I got a new input field and new button for adding, but when I click next time, I lose values which I enter before click...How I can make that values stay in input field when I click?

Here is a part of code that I write:

Part of JavaScript:

```
var counter = 1;
function dodajMenicu(e)
{
    var prviklik = document.getElementById('broj_menice[]').value;
    var provera = $(e).closest('div').find($("input[name*='broj_menice']")).val();
    if(prviklik == ''){
        alert("Unesite broj menice");
    }
    else if(provera == '')
    {
        alert('Unesite broj menice');
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var dodaj_menicu = "<div id="+counter+"><label for='broj_menice[]'>Broj menice: </label><input id='broj_menice[]' type='text' name='broj_menice[]' value='' ><label for='dodaj_menicu'>Dodaj menicu:</label><button type='button' id='dodaj_menicu"+counter+"' name='dodaj_menicu'  onClick='dodajMenicu(this);'> + </button></div>";           
        document.getElementById("dodatni_ispis").innerHTML = dodaj_menicu;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with your entire markup with it? (Pozdrav)

Comment: I would also highly appreciate an working example with HTML and JavaScript

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? Do you want to add another input field to your div, or create one when there is none inside? Currently, your script replaces all the content of `dodatni_ispis` div with a new input when a value is found, that's why you "loose" your value

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should append to existing innerHTML, instead of assigning the new value again and replacing the existing content